# Can I have ogr ExportToJson export with NO z coordinate?

Tags: python, geojson, ogr

I have code exporting a polygon to a json file, I would like to do this without the z coordinate since I don't need it and editing the database that was created from geodjango migrates looks painful.

So some way to tell this:
`poly.ExportToJson()`  to not include a z coordinate?

snippet that exports the json from a read in geotiff file:

```
for gcp in gcps:
    ring.AddPoint(gcp.GCPX, gcp.GCPY)

ring.AddPoint(gcps[0].GCPX, gcps[0].GCPY) #close off the polygon
    # Create polygon
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)
md = nitfData.GetMetadata()
print(filename) 
dic = {"sensor" : md['NITF_ISORCE'], "corner_coords" : md['NITF_IGEOLO'], "target_name" : md['NITF_TGTID'], "collection_dt" : md['NITF_IDATIM'], "f_size":os.path.getsize(path), "polarization" : md['NITF_FTITLE'], "mpoly" : poly.ExportToJson() }


jsonPaths.append(json.dumps(dic) + ',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove z coordinate like follow:

```
poly.FlattenTo2D()
```